# Conditional FROM statement Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to query a different table depending on a condition. Something like:

```
select * FROM
case when :myvar = 'A' then
   table A
when :myvar = 'B' then
   table B
else
   table C
end
```

EDIT:
All tables have the same columns but :myvar is a variable set externally. :myvar does not correspond to a value in any column

Comment: This design smells... Something is not right here. It's a lot easier to have a single table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all tables have the same columns, then use `union all`:

```
select a.* 
from a
where :myvar = 'A'
union all
select b.*
from b
where :myvar = 'B'
union all
select c.*
from c
where :myvar not in ('A', 'B');
```

If they do not have the same columns, then either `select` common columns from all the tables.  Or, give up:  A single `select` query returns a fixed set of columns.